# Как реализовать вычитание времени?

Tags: php

Как реализовать вычитание времени, скажем в 21:20 будет проводиться мероприятие а чтоб активировать ссылку в 20:45, ну чтоб два раза не писать а чтоб одним разом отняло

Comment: *а чтоб активировать ссылку в 20:45* - что Вы под этим подразумеваете ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два варианта. Оба варианта вычитают 35 минут.

Первый

```
echo date("H:i", strtotime('-35 minutes',strtotime('21:20')));
```

Второй

```
$dateTimeMinutesAgo = new DateTime("21:20");
$dateTimeMinutesAgo->sub(new DateInterval('PT35M'));
$dateTimeMinutesAgo = $dateTimeMinutesAgo->format("H:i");
echo $dateTimeMinutesAgo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял суть вопроса надо вычислить время за 35 минут до начала мероприятия?

```
echo date("H:i",strtotime('-35 minutes',strtotime('21:20')));
```